# PHP / Math - Getting grid values

Tags: php, math

So this might be quite bizarre, but... Imagine a grid of 10x10, each numbered left to right, top to down, starting at 1 and ending in 100.

I want to input a grid number (`$plot`) and get each grid number that surrounds it.

I started by making an array:

```
$plot = 45;
$arr = array(
    $plot-11, $plot-10, $plot-9, 
    $plot-1, $plot, $plot+1, 
    $plot+9, $plot+10, $plot+11
    );
```

This works fine.

[image]

Except if I add a plot near the edge of the grid (like `$plot = 50`) it would give me results at the start of the next row. Eg:

[image]

Any clever ways to solve this?

Comment: This looks like a math question rather than a PHP question?

Comment: what result do you expect? simply ignore the coordinates that are off-grid?

Comment: You should use a bi-dimensional array and check the bounds of the indices you use to access the data in it.

Comment: the data structure is too simplistic, you need to represent the actual grid, not simply a numeric ordering. Axiac's solution is sensible - a 2-dimensional array is ideal for representing a grid - you can use one dimension for rows and another for columns.

Comment: Why don't you try to add an if condition for *edges*? If they are x times of 10 or (x*10) + 1?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the array and only keep cells which have a  distance of 1 or 0:

```
$plot = 50;
$arr = array(
    $plot-11, $plot-10, $plot-9, 
    $plot-1, $plot, $plot+1, 
    $plot+9, $plot+10, $plot+11
    );

$plotX = ($plot - 1) % 10 + 1;
$plotY = ceil($plot / 10);

$arr = array_filter($arr, function($item) use($plotX, $plotY){
    return 1 >= abs($plotX - (($item - 1) % 10 + 1))
        && 1 >= abs($plotY - ceil($item / 10));
});

var_export($arr);
```

Result:

```
array (
  0 => 39,
  1 => 40,
  3 => 49,
  4 => 50,
  6 => 59,
  7 => 60,
)
```